# Kafka producer vs Kafka connect to read MySQL Datasource

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-kafka-connect

I have created a kafka producer that reads website click data streams from MySQL database and it works well. I found out that I can also just connect kafka to MySQL datasource using kafka connect or debezium. My target is to ingest the data using kafka and send it to Storm to consume and do analysis. It looks like both ways can achieve my target but using kafka producer may require me to build a kafka service that keeps reading the datasource.

Which of the two approaches would be more efficient for my  data pipe line?

Comment: Debezium would be preferred if you want fault tolerant code that you don't need to write yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice to not re-invent the wheel and use Debezium (disclaimer: I'm its project lead).

It's feature-rich (supported data types, configuration options, can do initial snapshotting etc.) and well tested in production. Another key aspect to keep in mind is that Debezium is based on reading the DB's log instead of polling (you might do the same in your producer, it's not clear from the question). This provides many advantages over polling:

- no delay as with low-frequency polls, no CPU load as with high-frequency polls
- can capture all changes without missing some between two polls
- can capture DELETEs
- no impact on schema (doesn't need a column to identify altered rows)

Comment: I want to stream web site click data such as from wikipedia to kafka then pass that to a data processor to consume. Web data-->DB-->debezium--> kafka --> data processor-->. I have started working with debezium and hope i can achieve my desired data pipeline.